# NextJS Call To API - Get Error Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: typescript, next.js, promise, next.js13

I have a nextjs app and am making a call to a nextjs backend.  I am getting an error in my nextjs page

Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'employeeStrengths[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 35 more.ts(2740)

Here is the page making the api call:

```
async function getData() {
  const results = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/employeeStrengths");

  if (!results.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return results;
}

const Employees = async () => {
  let data = await getData();

  return (
    <>
      <span className="font-bold text-4xl">Employees</span>
      <div className="container mx-auto py-10">
        <DataTable columns={columns} data={data} />. <==== data= gets flagged in error
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Employees;
```

Not sure how to correct the issue.

Thx in advance!

Comment: What is the line where that error originating? It is pretty self-explanatory: It is expecting to have the type `employeeStrengths[]` which is an array (has the length, pop, push, etc properties) but the type is `Response` instead, which is not an array.

Comment: Thanks, yes ... so return response.? as the results?

Comment: The response of fertch is an object. You need to get the data from it. Just read about the Fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch